# Portlet Using Other Portlet

Tags: liferay

I am having two portlets with following action methods

```
A-Portlet
public void actionMethodA(ActionRequest actionRequest,
ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
System.out.println("Portlet A");
}

B-Portlet
public void actionMethodB(ActionRequest actionRequest,
ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
System.out.println("Portlet B");
}
```

Can we call actionMethodB in B-Portlet ?

Comment: What do you mean by calling actionMethodB in B-portlet? When your action-url will have action parameter as actionMethodB, it will get called.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276042/display-liferay-portlet-inside-other-liferay-portlet and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134708/open-portlet-from-other-portlet

Answer (score 0):

Use `PortletClassInvoker` class to call a plugin method from another plugin.

Example:

```
try {
    methodKey = new MethodKey(
        ClassResolverUtil.resolveByPortletClassLoader(
        "com.acme.SyncFactoryRegistry",
        "custom-portlet"), "register", String.class,
        Object.class);
}
catch (RuntimeException re) {
    return;
}

PortletClassInvoker.invoke(
    false, "1_WAR_customportlet",
    _methodKey , arg1,  arg2);
```