# Liferay embed portlet into portlet

Tags: spring, liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

Is it possible in Liferay using Freemarker template language to embed portlets into portlets (not theme) ? I need to dynamically include portlets based on some query string or session.

I saw the in the Velocity world, they are doing it like this:

```
<div id="...">
    <runtime-portlet name="..." instance="..." queryString="..."/>
</div>
```

I also tried this way, but im getting "Expression theme.runtime is undefined" error.

```
${theme.runtime("portlet-id")}
```

I have seen solutions using iframe, but i dont really like it.

My environment:

- Liferay 6.2 ga2
- Portlet is built using Spring MVC + Freemarker
- JAVA 7

Any help or pointers would be really appreaciated.

Comment: See this forum discussion : https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/26522947

Comment: Maybe you'd like this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23134708/open-portlet-from-other-portlet

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, you need to modify $theme.runtime() method with additional parameters.

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme