# How can I open a pop up of my JSF portlet's edit mode?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay

When opening the configuration mode of a Liferay portlet it opens in a pop up dialog:

[image: Configuration Mode Dialog]

How can I get my JSF portlet to open a similar pop up but for edit mode of my JSF portlet?

I am using Liferay 6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In Liferay 6.2+:

For the most part, you can open edit mode of a JSF portlet [the same way for both JSF and JSP portlets: via the client-side JS `Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow()` method](https://www.liferay.com/web/pokuri.jayaram/blog/-/blogs/portlet-in-popup-window-in-liferay-6-2). To create the dialog, you will need to get a render URL for the portlet in edit mode and pop up state via [`portlet:renderURL`](https://www.liferayfaces.org/doc/faces/vdldoc/bridge-api/4.1/portlet/renderURL.html):

```
<portlet:renderURL var="popUpEditModeURL" escapeXml="false"
    portletMode="edit" windowState="pop_up" />
```

Then use the URL in the `Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow()` method:

```
<h:outputScript>
    AUI().use('liferay-util-window', function(A) {
        var popUp = Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow({
            dialog: {
                centered: true,
                constrain2view: true,
                resizable: false
            }
        }).plug(A.Plugin.DialogIframe, {
            autoLoad: true,
            iframeCssClass: 'dialog-iframe',
            uri:'#{popUpEditModeURL}'
        }).render();

        // call `popUp.show();` to show the dialog.
    });
</h:outputScript>
```

Then call `popUp.show()` whenever you want to show the portlet in edit mode.

Alternatively, you could use a [Liferay Faces Alloy's dialog](http://liferayfaces.org/web/guest/showcase/-/component/alloy/dialog/general) (or any other component suite's dialog) with an `iframe` inside it to show edit mode in a dialog:

```
<alloy:dialog height="95%" width="95%" clientKey="dialog">
    <iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="${popUpEditModeURL}" />
</alloy:dialog>
```

However, this method may not produce exactly the same effect as using `Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow()`.

**Full disclosure:** I am one of the developers of Liferay Faces Alloy.