# How to embed a portlet in an in-page popup in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui, alloy-ui

From JavaScript, I need to create an in-page (DIV-based?) popup that shows a particular portlet.

This looks exactly like what I need:
https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Pop-up+in+Liferay

> Liferay provides a class called Expanse.Popup to implement this type of pop ups. Here is how this type of pop up would look like:
>   [image]
>   This javascript code will make an asynchronous call to the url we give it and will place the content in our page. Below there is an example which will load the url 'url' in a pop up called 'our title':
>
> var popup = new Expanse.Popup(
>   [...]

**Problem:** Unfortunately, when I put that code in my portlet and deploy&run it, I get:

```
TypeError: Expanse.Popup is not a function
```

According to the comments at that page, the function has changed names many times. I have tried `Alloy.Popup`, `A.Popup`, `Liferay.Popup`, all fail in a similar way. Also, I have read that AUI is deprecated and not recommended for new development.

`Liferay.Util.openWindow` works but unfortunately it takes an URL as a parameter, rather than a portlet. Is there any way to make it show a portlet? I don't want to create a page for this on all sites.

**Question:** How to implement this in-page popup that loads a portlet, in Liferay 7?
*It can be modal or not: I don't mind if users can let the popup open and interact with the rest of the page.*

Comment: Try the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35162383/how-can-i-open-a-pop-up-of-my-jsf-portlets-edit-mode/35162384#35162384. You will need to change it a little since it's JSF specific, but it should be easy to change for a JSP.

Answer (score 2):

The openWindow is a good approach. If you look at the portlet options and how a configuration dialogue gets opened you get something like this

```
Liferay.Portlet.openWindow({
bodyCssClass: 'dialog-with-footer',
destroyOnHide: true,
namespace: '_com_liferay_polls_web_portlet_PollsDisplayPortlet_INSTANCE_qOP6anrnoY5o_',
portlet: '#p_p_id_com_liferay_polls_web_portlet_PollsDisplayPortlet_INSTANCE_qOP6anrnoY5o_',
portletId: 'com_liferay_polls_web_portlet_PollsDisplayPortlet_INSTANCE_qOP6anrnoY5o',
title: 'ASDF',
uri: 'portlet render url'
```

});

The URL is required to pinpoint the portlet that you actually would like to render but you can generate one for you easily by the liferay-portlet:renderURL tag(it takes the portlet id as parameter) or you can construct if your self if you know the syntax(not recommended)